# Accessing the values of a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, many-to-many

I've created a Many to Many relationship in my project like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(_('User Name'), max_length=150, unique=True)
    # and a lot of other fields and stuff


class Course(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="enrollments", blank=True, null=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(_("Course Name"), max_length=200)
```

In Django Admin site, I created some courses and added users to it. What I need is **to get a list of courses that a unique user is enrolled** and **a list of users enrolled in a unique course.**

I know that I can access the Related Manager like this:

```
user.enrollments

<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f4df159c0a0>
```

And I know also that I can access the intermediate m2m class using:

```
user.enrollments.through

<class 'core.models.Course_user'>
```

What I could not get (or find in the docs or even in internet at all) is how I can access the **values** contained in this relation (courses a user is enrolled and users enrolled in a course).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.enrollments` is a *manager*, just like `Course.objects` is a manager. You can create a `QuerySet` of the objects by using the [**`.all()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all):

```
user.enrollments.all()  # collection of Courses user is enrolled in
```

and we can query for the users enrolled in a `Course` object *`course`*:

```
course.user.all()  # users enrolled in course
```

Comment: Nice and simple, many thanks! I thought it could be so simple that docs and internet won't show. I never get to that info though.